# getting the filenames of attachments in a Notes document

Tags: java, xpages

What is the easiest way to get the file name of an attachment in a Notes document in Java?

In my case the document always contains maximum 1 file and are stored in a rich text field called Body.

Comment: Have a look in the help file for the EmbeddedObject class and use getName() on this. There's an example that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your own java class, it should work:

```
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getAttachmentsNames(RichTextItem richTextItem) {
    List<String> attachmentsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Vector v = richTextItem.getEmbeddedObjects();
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            EmbeddedObject eo = (EmbeddedObject) e.nextElement();
            if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) attachmentsNames.add(eo.getName());
        }
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return attachmentsNames;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getFileNames(Document document, String richTextFieldName) {
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        if (document.hasEmbedded()) {

            Vector<String> docFileNames = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession().evaluate("@AttachmentNames" , document);              
            RichTextItem rtitem = (RichTextItem) document.getFirstItem(richTextFieldName); // Body


            for (int i = 0; i < docFileNames.size(); i++) {
                if (!docFileNames.get(i).equals("") && getAttachmentsNames(rtitem).contains(docFileNames.get(i))) {
                    fileNames.add(fileNames.get(i));
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```